# Find a system of linear equations representing a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a vector subspace V=Span {(1,-1,0,2,1); (0,2,3,1,-1); (1,0,2,1,-1)}

I need to find a system of linear equations representing V.

I don't need a full solution, just to be pointed in the right direction. Or is it just x1 - x2 + 2x4 + x5 (etc. repeated for the next two rows).

Thanks

Comment: $x_1-x_2+2x_4+x_5$ is not in and of itself an "*equation.*"  There is no equals sign.  That said... in what way do you want the space to be representable by a system of linear equations?  Are you wanting your span to be the *range* of the space?  The *solution set* of the space?  Something else?

Comment: Point taken. I'm not sure, I'm going through a homework and that's all the information that has been given I'm afraid.